# How to write this JavaScript function so that it gets invoked multiple times and what is the concept called?

Tags: javascript

So I'm tackling a coding kata that requires me to write a function that: accepts any number of parameters and returns the product of every single parameter given.

The kata answer says you can make a call like this:

```
MultiplyNums(1, 3)(2)
```

I wrote mine like this (which of course won't work for the case above):

```
function MultiplyNums() {
  var prod = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
    prod = prod * arguments[i];
  }
  return prod;
}
```

How do I write the function so that it does and what is this concept called (if it has a name)?  It "looks" like immediate function invocation even though I know that refers to something else.

Also, what if I wanted to do both types of calls:

```
MultiplyNums(1, 3)(2) //one type of call

MultiplyNums(1, 5) //another type of call
```

Comment: The concept is called currying.

Comment: You can check higher order function or currying

Comment: Does the first function call return `6` or `3`? I'm not sure if the second number in parentheses represents the number of parameters or the number to multiply by.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The concept is called currying, and you nearly had it!

`prod` should be initialized to `1` so that you aren't multiplying by `0`, and it should return a function.

```js
function MultiplyNums() {
  var prod = 1;
  for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++)
    prod *= arguments[i];
  return function(num) {
    return prod * num;  
  };
}

console.log(MultiplyNums(3, 1)(2));
```

Comment: Thanks your answer is great, what if I also wanted to do a normal call (as above - such as MultiplyNums(1,5)? Would that change anything? It seems like it would.

Comment: That wouldn't be possible, because there's no way for the function to know which version you're trying to call, and numbers aren't functions. You could make the second function accept zero parameters, so that you could do `MultiplyNums(1,5)()`